# Finding all class declarations than inherit from another with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a `CSharpCompilation` instance containing an array of `SyntaxTree`s and I am trying to find all the class declarations that inherit from a class

e.g

```
// Not in syntax tree but referenced in project
public class Base{}

// In syntax tree, how to find all such classes?
public class MyClass : Base {}
```

I've tried a few things but am a bit confused with all the options and can't seem to find the right way to do this.

I've tried to get the symbols but this doesn't work for inherited types

```
SyntaxTree[] trees = context.CSharpCompilation.SyntaxTrees;
IEnumerable<ISymbol> symbols = context.CSharpCompilation.GetSymbolsWithName(x => x == typeof(Base).Name, SymbolFilter.Type);
```

Quite new to Roslyn and would be most grateful for any suggestions or pointers for how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I came up with the following which will recursively check all classes for the inherited type

```
public class BaseClassRewriter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    private readonly SemanticModel _model;

    public BaseClassRewriter(SemanticModel model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        var symbol = _model.GetDeclaredSymbol(node);
        if (InheritsFrom<BaseClass>(symbol))
        {
            // hit!
        }
    }

    private bool InheritsFrom<T>(INamedTypeSymbol symbol)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (symbol.ToString() == typeof(T).FullName)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (symbol.BaseType != null)
            {
                symbol = symbol.BaseType;
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't handle generics.  Look at http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Shared/Extensions/ITypeSymbolExtensions.cs,310

Comment: Thanks for that, the extensions for ITypeSymbol and INamedTypeSymbol look useful but are internal at the moment. 
I've checked my use case for this code and fortunately I do not need to worry about generics as for my purposes at least, the base class I'm looking for is never generic.

Comment: What you can do is expose them in your project and make them private.  I can't exactly tell you how but back at my old job this  winter,  we use those classes for analysis

Answer (score 7):

First you'll need to get the symbol for Base. If this is a particular type you know about in advance, you can use [Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/Compilation.cs,b69619b653a39389,references) for this. That link will also show you over 100 examples of that method in use.

From there, it depends on what you're trying to do. If you're doing this from inside an analyzer (which I suspect from the "context.CSharpCompilation" in your code), and you're trying to identify and then check some property of these derived types, you could use [RegisterSymbolAction](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/DiagnosticAnalyzer/DiagnosticAnalysisContext.cs,236e3d67294cd8c4,references) for SymbolKind.NamedType, and then check each type's [BaseType](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/ITypeSymbol.cs,7d2bdbfdbe83771c,references) (possibly recursively, depending on what you're trying to accomplish) to see if you find the type discovered by GetTypeByMetadataName above.

If you're doing solution-wide analysis outside the context of an analyzer, then there's a [helper for this](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Shared/Extensions/INamedTypeSymbolExtensions.cs,913cf9f3a8fdbd8c,references) in the Roslyn codebase, but it's internal. There's an [existing request](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/64) to make ITypeSymbolExtensions public, so I've mentioned this thread in that request and suggested expanding it to include INamedTypeSymbolExtensions.

Comment: Thanks for this useful info, will research more.

Actually I'm doing this inside a SyntaxRewriter and after a few hours of pain have come up with a method which is probably naive and your info will show me a much better way. Have included the code in another answer rather than comments

Comment: Links are dead. It would have been nice to include the relevant example.

Comment: link is dead -1

Comment: . . . . . . . . R.I.P. . . . . . . . .

Comment: [Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/0b5b74454d2f38219ce9ed7715a85a821f18a550/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/Compilation/Compilation.cs#L1183)

Answer (score 1):

```
var classDecSynList = classDecSynList.Where(x=>
       (((IdentifierNameSyntax(x.BaseList.Types.FirstOrDefault()))
              .Identifier.ValueText=="Base"));
```

Assuming you have all the class declaration Syntax list;

Comment: This only checks direct inheritance.