# Finding all not inheriting C# classes with Roslyn and changing to inheriting from base object (java-like)

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm working on a little Roslyn project that includes changing parse tree and writing changes back to file. I've started with standalone code analyzer and want to build it as a command line app. I've encountered a challenge, though.
Working with:
[Find classes which derive from a specific base class with Roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31505199/find-classes-which-derive-from-a-specific-base-class-with-roslyn) partially, and mostly with:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Syntax-Analysis I've created this small project:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (args.Length < 1)
                throw new ArgumentException();
            SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(File.ReadAllText(args[0]));
            var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax) tree.GetRoot();
            var classes = from ClassDeclarationSyntax in root.DescendantNodesAndSelf() select ClassDeclarationSyntax;
            foreach (var c in classes)
            {
                if (/*Not inheriting*/)
                {
                    /*Add inherition*/
                }
            }
            /*Write changes to file*/
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fatal error ocured.");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

As comments in code states, I need to check whether the class is inheriting from something or not (and choose second option) then change the parse tree and at last write it to file, for now I'd be glad to know how to check "not inheritance" only, although any directions for step two and three are welcome too. The File to parse and change is supplied by path as program parameter here:

```
if (args.Length < 1)
    throw new ArgumentException();
SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(File.ReadAllText(args[0]));
```

---

**SOLUTION** 
With support from received answers I've come up with working app.
Here's my code, maybe not perfect but working

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (args.Length < 1)
                throw new ArgumentException();
            SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(File.ReadAllText(args[0]));
            var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax) tree.GetRoot();
            IdentifierNameSyntax iname = SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("Object");
            BaseTypeSyntax bts = SyntaxFactory.SimpleBaseType(iname);
            SeparatedSyntaxList<BaseTypeSyntax> ssl = new SeparatedSyntaxList<BaseTypeSyntax>();
            ssl = ssl.Add(bts);
            BaseListSyntax bls = SyntaxFactory.BaseList(ssl);
            bool x = true;
            while(x) //Way to handle all nodes due to impossibility to handle more than one in foreach
            {
                foreach (var c in root.DescendantNodesAndSelf())
                {
                    x = false;
                    var classDeclaration = c as ClassDeclarationSyntax;
                    if (classDeclaration == null)
                        continue;
                    if (classDeclaration.BaseList != null) //Inherits
                        continue;
                    else //Not inherits
                    {
                        root = root.ReplaceNode(classDeclaration, classDeclaration.WithBaseList(bls));
                        x = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (args.Length > 1) //Write to given file
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(args[1], FileMode.Open)))
                {
                    root.WriteTo(sw);
                }
            else //Overwrite source
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(args[0], FileMode.Open)))
                {
                    root.WriteTo(sw);
                }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fatal error ocured.");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ClassDeclarationSyntax` has `BaseList` that contains `Types`. So you can retrieve information about base classes use these fields:

```
        foreach (var c in correctRoot.DescendantNodesAndSelf())
        {
            var classDeclaration = c as ClassDeclarationSyntax;
            if (classDeclaration == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (classDeclaration.BaseList?.Types.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This class has base class or it implements interfaces");
            }
            else
            {
                /*Add inherition*/
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately, you need extra logic to distinguish that your class has base class or it just implements interfaces. If you want to solve this you need to analyze ***base object***(class/interface) using `semantical model` to get info about corresponding `ISymbol` or try to find declaration of these nodes in the `syntax tree`, if this declaration is defined in your projects/solutions.

Also if you want to add inheritation to class you need to set into `BaseList` a new created node using `SyntaxFactory.SimpleBaseType(...)` and `SyntaxFactory.BaseList(...)`

Comment: Isn't it just simplier to compare `BaseList` to `null`? From what i've experimented it works too.

Comment: @RobertGrzesiak Well, I don't know example when comparison between `BaseList` and `null` wouldn't works, but I have not been found a some documentation which explains that `BaseList` cannot be null when class has base class or implements interfaces. So I'm not sure that this comparison will be work in all cases or not.

Comment: You're totally right `BaseList` exist only if class inherits or implements something. So `BaseList != null` should work just fine from what I understand.

Comment: @RobertGrzesiak sorry, my previous comment have a one mistake in my reasoning: I'm not sure that `BaseList` always will be null when class doesn't have base class or doesn't implement any interfaces.