# How to tell classes from interfaces in Roslyn's `BaseList`?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, roslyn

I am using [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) to analyze C# code. One of the things I need to have is analyzing a class declaration node and get information about:

- Its base class
- Its implemented interfaces

I can get access to the class declaration node (type `ClassDeclarationSyntax`), and from there I can get access to the `BaseList`:

```
ClassDeclarationSyntax node = ...; // The class declaration
BaseListSyntax baseList = node.BaseList;
```

However `baseList` contains both interfaces and classes. I need ti distinguish classes from interfaces. How?

#### Do I need to use the `SemanticModel`?

I've searched [Roslyn's Wiki](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki) and discovered that it is possible to access semantic information from my AST.

```
SyntaxTree programRoot = ...; // Getting the AST root
CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("Program")
    .AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(
    typeof(object).Assembly.Location))
    .AddSyntaxTrees(programRoot);
```

But how to get those info from here?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234052/finding-all-class-declarations-than-inherit-from-another-with-roslyn

Comment: Actually my question is slightly different from that right? I mean, Yes in the end looks like the solution is the same, but here I am trying, more specifically, to distinguish between classes and interfaces.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand your question properly, sorry mate!

Comment: Absolutely no problem, it is always good to analyze questions and report possible duplicates. Actually thanks to you I could find a question which is related to mine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

The syntax tree just knows what words are where; it doesn't know anything about what an identifier refers to.

You need to get the SemanticModel from the compilation), then call `GetSymbolInfo()` on each identifier node in the list.  You can then cast the symbol to `ITypeSymbol` to find out about the type.